# Php-Mysql transactions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have to run a set of queries for each id in a for loop. Now i want to implement transactions for the same. Given below is the code structure

```
for($i=0;i<$test;$i++) {
    begin() //start transactions

    while($j<4) {
        Insertquery($j) //run an insert query
        $j++;
        if($mysql_errno!=0) { //check for any error in mysql query,if error rollback
            rollback();
            break;
        }

    } //end of while loop

    commit();
}//end of for loop
```

Now if i run the for loop for only one iteration roll back for those queries work, but if i run the for loop for few iterations and in between if any query is incorrect the roll back for that set does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use query execution inside loop.

Just collect all ids and begin the transaction.

```
begin() //start transactions
$sql = "insert into table name (t1,t2) values ";
while($j<4) {
  $sql .= "($t1, $t2),";
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1).';';
if(!mysql_query($sql))
{
    rollback();
}

commit();
```

Comment: It is a set of 4 different select insert statements so i can't combine the statements as suggested